# Having trouble removing "Enter" from variables

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

So the code I'm currently running will extract strings from slides in ppt, and some of these string may come with spaces or enters/line breaks. The code bellow is what I have, and it works great to remove spaces but it won't work for the Enters/line breaks.

```
pptText = Shpe.TextFrame.TextRange
pptText = LCase(Replace(pptText," ",""))
pptText = Replace(pptText,vbNewLine,"")
```

When there is a text that has been input like this:

`iq_42, iq_26,
iq_72`

In the debugger, the variable pptText will look like this:

`pptText = iq_42, iq_26,iq_72`

But there is a character saved in that variable that the debugger isn't showing which messes with the rest of my program.

I've tried Trim and Replace and I've tried using vbNewLine/vbCrLf/vbCr/vbLf to identify the Enter/line break without any success.

Any ideas on how to remove all traces of "enter"?

Comment: Use [Trim()](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php) function.

Comment: Try `Replace(Value, vbLf & vbCr, vbNullString)`

Comment: @Kostas K. Does using the `&` operator work just like K Davises Edit below?

Comment: @Pinlop Yep, it's the same thing.

Comment: @Kostas K. I tried `pptText = Replace(pptText, vbCrLf & vbCr & vbLf, vbNullString)` instead of `pptText = Replace(Replace(Replace(pptText, vbCrLf, vbNullString), vbCr, vbNullString), vbLf, vbNullString)` and it didn't work. Am I typing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

### Edit

As wisely suggested by [@Kostas K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7923463/kostas-k), here is the function version

```
Function RemoveEnter(ByVal YourString As String) As String
    RemoveEnter = Replace(Replace(Replace(YourString, vbCrLf, ""), vbCr, ""), vbLf, "")
End Function
```

Comment: Why don't you make this a function to return a new String? ;)

Comment: This one worked for me! For some reason using all three together worked but using them separetely did not... strange. I just have this set as `pptText = Replace(Replace(Replace(pptText, vbCrLf, vbNullString), vbCr, vbNullString), vbLf, vbNullString)` in a line in the middle of my code. would I benefit from making it a function?

Comment: @Pinlop Only if you intend on using multiple times, so you wouldn't have to type it out each time you need it. Otherwise, you can use it as you have it.

Comment: @K. Davis Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
pptText = Replace(pptText, Chr$(10), "")
```

This replaces the newline character (CHAR(10) in Excel) with nothing. You can also do "Chr(10)". The dolla $ign just says "return this as a string value."